# Test automation with docker, travis and a large database

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I'm setting up an environment that would run selenium tests on a docker container on travis. I have a concept of how this should work but would like to hear from others if this is the correct way:

1. Push a docker image (lets call it base-img) that contains nginx, mysql, php with a populated database to my private docker registry
2. Trigger travis to test. Travis should then:

   - pull the base-img
   - put my project folder into the right directory on base-img
   - create the required selenium container and link it with base-img
   - start the tests

It would probably be better to run nginx, mysql, etc. on separate    containers. We have a base image from our hosting provider which we      intend to use as it should give us an environment that is practically    the same as in production. The image already has all these stuff installed. I only need to create a new image with an imported database. I intend to do this every day with the production database. The database is huge (around 15GB) and would take travis a while to pull.  Should such large databases even be used for travis or should they be stripped down to the minimum? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

The setup itself is sound. Extrapolating from my experience (using ~1.8GB images) pulling a >15GB image (from hub.docker.com) would take upwards of 20 minutes. That would leave < 30 minutes for actual tests, assuming you're on travis-ci.org. Another argument against using the production DB is reproducibility of test results. I'd say you should at least also test against a not constantly changing DB as a control.